# implementing a kal calendar into a tabbar applicaition

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, calendar

I want to use the kal calendar framework. But I don't know how to implement this into a tabbar application. When I look at the demo of how to initialize a kalViewController, it looks like this.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    KalViewController *calendar = [[KalViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:calendar animated:YES];
}
```

This works but It goes to another view. And I want it to show in the same view, using a storyboard.

Comment: so I should just copy all the code from KalViewController in my own viewController class ?

Comment: Oké that would not be the best solution. But what do you suggest then ?

Comment: lol I do know the basics, my problem is that I have a tabbar inside a navigationController. And I'm working with storyboards

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21388/discussion-between-stef-geelen-and-vikingosegundo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked the KalViewController class. It has no `initWithCoder:` implementation, the initializer that is called if instantiated from nibs/storyboards.

I added this to make it work:

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    if ((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])) {

        NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
        logic = [[KalLogic alloc] initForDate:date];
        self.initialDate = date;
        self.selectedDate = date;
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(significantTimeChangeOccurred) name:UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification object:nil];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reloadData) name:KalDataSourceChangedNotification object:nil];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Than I just dragged an UIViewController onto the storybord stage, changed it class in the inspector to KalViewController, wired it up from the tabbar controller and it worked.

---

I created a sample project: [TabbedKalTest@GitHub](https://github.com/vikingosegundo/TabbedKalTest)

---

Of course DRY should be in mind:

```
-(void) _configureWithDate:(NSDate *)date
{
    logic = [[KalLogic alloc] initForDate:date];
    self.initialDate = date;
    self.selectedDate = date;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(significantTimeChangeOccurred) name:UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reloadData) name:KalDataSourceChangedNotification object:nil];
}

//called if created by nib/storyboard
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    if ((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])) {
        [self _configureWithDate:[NSDate date]];
    }
    return self;
}

//the designated initializer for non-nib/storyboard creation
- (id)initWithSelectedDate:(NSDate *)date
{
  if ((self = [super init])) {
    [self _configureWithDate:date];
  }
  return self;
}
```

---

I created a branch to fix this in Kal and posted a [pull-request](https://github.com/klazuka/Kal/pull/75).

Comment: You are a genious!  But can you please explain briefly what you are doing over here ? So in the future I can also write that magical code !

Comment: you mean in the `initWithCoder:`?

Comment: Yes;) also one problem. On the simulater it craches with the following error.Assertion failure in -[KalMonthView tileForDate:], /Users/geelenstef/Desktop/Appmax/Kal/src/KalMonthView.m:86
2012-12-19 16:08:20.723 Offitel[10906:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Failed to find corresponding tile for date 0/0/0'

Comment: That crash is why I added that implementation of `initWithCoder:`. As the designated initializer is not call when instantiating from storyboard, the KalViewController would be in an illegal stated and a assert in the month view triggers this. to avoid this, I copied the implementation from `initWithSelectedDate:` to `initWithCoder:` — a cleaner solution would be to call the same configuration method from both initializers.

Comment: Oké but how is it possible that it works on real device but not on the simulator ?

Comment: I changed the code to use a helper method

Comment: Why should it not work on the real device?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21394/discussion-between-stef-geelen-and-vikingosegundo)

Comment: i got same error. i use the kalview, not kalviewcontroller. so, where can i add this initWithCoder . i add kalview as subview in one of my viewcontrolle. i not use storyboard but create kalview with programatically. please help me.

Comment: Have a look on my pull request. Or use it directly.